# What does Potrefená mean in Czech?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary, czech

There is a restaurant chain in the Czech Republic called the `Potrefená Husa`.  `Husa` in Czech is Goose, but I can't find a meaning for `Potrefená` in any of my usual sources (Google Translate, dict.cc, etc.,). Does anyone know if this word has a meaning?

(I would ask this on a Czech-specific SE, but it looks like such a site does not exist.)

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potrefen%C3%A1_husa_se_v%C5%BEdycky_ozve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Potrefená* is a feminine gender past passive participle of the perfective verb *potrefit* “to hit”, its imperfective counterpart [*trefit*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trefit) has the same English translation, “to hit”. This verb is a borrowing from German *treffen* “to meet, to encounter; to hit, to strike. So, *potrefená* means “[the one that was] hit, struck”, and *potrefená husa* means “the hit goose, the goose that was hit”.

This expression used as the name of restaurants is both quite clever and funny at once, since *potrefená husa* comes from a number of proverbs and sayings about a guilty or suspected person unintentionally disclosing oneself, like *Potrefená husa se vždycky ozve* – “The hit goose will always call back” mentioned in the comment above by @user6726, or *Potrefená husa nejvíc kejhá* — “The hit goose honks the most” — meaning the person concerned/guilty will disclose oneself by raising some comments, objections, confirmations, etc.